# R multiple boxplot visualization

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have data in a csv consisting of more than 4000 entries and a glimpse of the data in it looks like this:

```
Variant Metric        Value
I       Accuracy    76.14708
I       F-measure   0.87
II      Accuracy    76.23548
III     Accuracy    76.07839
IV      Time        0.56
```

As the metrics are on a different scale I am unable to get a proper view of the box plots for
time and f-measure metrics:

[image]

The R code is as follows:

```
df <- read.csv("NBboxplot.csv", header=T)
require(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x=Variant, y=Value)) + 
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill=Metric))
p + facet_wrap( ~ Variant, scales="free")
```

Any clue towards better visualization?

Comment: I think it might be better to set `facet_wrap` to `facet_wrap( ~ Metric, 
              scales="free_y")`. In this way, each facet will contain metrics with similar values, while mantaining all the x axis values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change the facet to `Metric`, as these are on drastically different scales:

```
p <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x=Variant, y=Value)) + 
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill=Metric)) + 
  facet_wrap(~Metric, scales="free")
```